# Pow function in C outputting strange values

Tags: c, pow

I am having trouble using the pow function in c. The following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>  

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    double t;
    for(t = 2; t <= 7; t++)
    {
        double num = pow(7,t);
        printf("pi(%d) =",  pow(7,t));
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
pi(1075576832) =pi(807) =pi(431) =pi(53) =pi(701) =pi(323)
```

instead of outputting `pi(49) = pi(7^3) =` and so on.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That's because of wrong modifier. Use `%f` for `double` numbers: `printf("pi(%f) =",  pow(7,t));`